How to Connect To Raspberry Pi With An X11-Enabled SSH Session Using Visual Studio Code On A Windows 10 PC?
I have a Windows 10 PC (WinPC) connected directly to a Raspberry Pi (RPi) via Ethernet LAN. How can I connect to the RPi with an X11-enabled SSH session using Visual Studio Code?
In the following screenshot, you can see my Visual Studio Code on the WinPC, where I am already connected via Remote-SSH to the RPi. What should I type to check if X11 forwarding works?


WinPC:

Windows 10 Pro 22H2
Visual Studio Code 1.94.2

RPi:

Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1

PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)" NAME="Debian GNU/Linux" VERSION_ID="12" VERSION="12 (bookworm)" VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm ID=debian HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/" SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

Linux raspberrypi 6.6.31+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.31-1+rpt1 (2024-05-29) aarch64 GNU/Linux



Which Pi? What OS is installed (detail including version)?

hey milliways, thanks for reply, i edited my question. best regards

Note that Win 11 can easily be set up to be an X11 server.

By default Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm DOES NOT use X11 but Wayfire (although X is used on older devices with insufficient memory but you can configure it to use X). raspi-config can show/change what is used.
The following script shows network system (but not protocol).
#! /bin/sh
# Check status of networking
checkactive () {
if [ $(systemctl is-active $1) = 'active' ]; then
    echo $1 'active'
fi
}
checkactive 'systemd-networkd'
checkactive 'dhcpcd'
checkactive 'NetworkManager'
checkactive 'wpa_supplicant'

echo
echo "Network devices"
ls /sys/class/net/

ps -e | grep X should show if X active.
